# How to fake DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, fakeiteasy

I'm writing a unit test for `ConsumerService` that uses EntityFramework Core. Below you can see my `AppDBContext` class, and its **one and only** constructor. In order to fake it, I'm required **to pass DbContext into** it, so, I'm trying to fake that one too. I'm having an issue faking the **DbContext** object.

Here is my `AppDBContext` class:

```
   public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

**Consumer **class then wires it in like this:

```
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public ConsumerService(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for the **consumer** class.

I've tried this:

```
        private readonly DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> _options;
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        private readonly ConsumerService _consumerService ;

        public ConsumerServiceTests()
        {
            //Dependencies
            _options = A.Fake<DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>>();
            _db = A.Fake<AppDbContext>(x => x.WithArgumentsForConstructor(() => new AppDbContext(_options)));

            //SUT
            _consumerService = new ConsumerService(_db);
        }
```

I'm getting this error:

Message: 
FakeItEasy.Core.FakeCreationException :
Failed to create fake of type API.Data.AppDbContext:
No constructor matches the passed arguments for constructor.
An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was caught during this call. Its message was:
The DbContextOptions passed to the AppDbContextProxy constructor must be a DbContextOptions. When registering multiple DbContext types, make sure that the constructor for each context type has a DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic DbContextOptions parameter.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
at API.Data.AppDbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in C:\Users\...\API\Data\AppDbContext.cs:line 8 at Castle.Proxies.AppDbContextProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[], DbContextOptions`1 options)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

*NOTE*

1. I use FakeItEasy.
2. No, I **don't** want to use InMemoryDatabase. I need to fake DbContext.

Comment: If you want to test make a copy of the database and connect to copy.

Comment: @jdweng Please read the Note section

Comment: _"I need to fake DbContext."_ - But why? Sound like [XY-problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: @GuruStron AppDbContext has it as a dependency. And ConsumerService has AppDbContext as dependency. And it is the only constructor that AppDbContext has. So I need to fake it, in order to pass it then to fake AppDbContext

Comment: Just new up an instance of it - `new DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>()`. There is absolutely no point in faking it.

Comment: I read it.  Making a copy isn't a InMemoryDatabase.  It is an new instance of the database.

Comment: @jdweng Why would I do that for a Unit Test?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm not sure what happened, but it worked. You can't imagine how many combinations I tried. I mean I was sure I already done that. Thanks

Comment: You do not want to modify an existing database with vital info.

Comment: @fredward this is because the members of the fake DbContextOptions returns dummy values unless configured. So `_options.ContextType` returns a fake type, instead of `AppDbContext`. So [this check](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/0c5ae3bed7cc1323df3b6fd29d7f95f2cb406d36/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L111) fails in the DbContext constructor. Using a real DbContextOptions returns the expected type, so it works.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you are trying to mock concrete classes? Usually, IoC means that you should replace concrete implementations with interfaces or abstract classes and mock them instead.

Comment: @EvgenyShmanev I needed to pass it to the AppDbContext constructor. I thought It was necessary to mock, but then Guru Stron explained that i can just create a new instance instead of Faking it.

Comment: Correct. When you work with concrete classes, you should not mock them. When there is dependency of an interface, the interface should be mocked. Btw, I would rather introduce a new interface IAppDbContext and pass it to the consumer service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually use `InMemoryDatabase` for testing my services. By the way you should Instantiate a `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().Options;
```

It gives you what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class and then use it in other classes by inheriting it, like:

```
public abstract class BaseDbContext
{
  protected AppDbContext _db;
  
  public BaseDbContext()
  {
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlite("DataSource:=memory:", _ => {});
    _db = new AppDbContext(builder.Options);
    _db.Database.OpenConnection();
    _db.Database.EnsureCreated();
  }
}
```